# Why has git fetch stopped working after some rev-parse commands?

Tags: git

git fetch suddenly stopped working. Here are the commands I used:

```
git fetch
From ssh://git-server/path/to/repo
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master

ls .git/branches 

cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master 
<sha1>

git rev-parse U
U
fatal: ambiguous argument 'U': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

git rev-parse master
<another sha1>

git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{upstream}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'master'

git fetch                                     
<no output>
```

Any idea what I've done to break things?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is broken. You're up to date and `git fetch` has silently fetched nothing.

Try `git fetch --verbose` and it will tell you that all your remote branches are up to date.

Comment: Then why did it create output earlier?

Comment: Because, earlier, you weren't up to date. Note the `new branch` line. By the way, `git fetch`'s output is tremendously confusing. The `new branch` output means that your Git thinks their `master` is new on *their side*. Your Git created an `origin/master` as a result. But your Git did not create a local branch named `master` due to the fetch.

Comment: It looks like you did create your own branch `master` *before* you ran `git fetch`, so you now have an `origin/master` that finds some commit hash ID, and a `master` that finds some commit hash ID. These are probably two different commit hash IDs. If they are the same hash ID (I can't tell from what you've posted in the original question), all you have left to do is `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`.

Comment: It is confusing. git fetch is silent if up to date but git pull will output "Already up-to-date.".

Comment: Another indication that things went fine : check the command's exit code (in bash : `echo $?` right after running `git fetch`, or `git fetch && echo "ok"`)